# Printing 10 integers per line

Tags: java

I have this code. This code simply creates an array of size 1,000,000 to hold randomly generated integers. My problem is that i want to print 10 integers per line and the output is so strange and i don`t know why. I debugged the code and found that the code must work as expected. Though, it acts strangely. I will be grateful if anyone can help me. This is my code:

```
Integer[] list = new Integer[1000000];
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++)
list[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
 
//print 10 integers per line
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++){
if( (i+1) % 10 == 0)
  System.out.printf("%-5d\n" , list[i]);
else
  System.out.printf("%-5d" , list[i]);
}
```

I attach a screenshot of the output.
[image]

By the way: I use Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Works for me. Can you please [edit] you post and make sure you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Console cycle buffer size is 1024 KB (default for Intellij idea), you can see it in `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console`. So your `1,000,000` random numbers more than that. In the first line of your console after program is executed, you do not see real first line, it is somewhere in the middle of process. So, that line is cut. If you print 1000 numbers, you will see that your code works fine.

---

**Edit:**

In above-mentioned settings location, there is an option **Override console buffer size**, click on the check box, increase buffer size. When size is big enough, you can see all your numbers in the form of 10 numbers per line.

Comment: So, what can i do to overcome this problem? @Sercan

Comment: You can override the cycle buffer size in `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console`

Comment: I overrided it and the output is the same @Sercan

Comment: It should be big enough to show 1,000,000 integer

Comment: by how many can i increase the console buffer size? @Sercan

Comment: I just checked that you it printed 20,560 lines, each line have 10 numbers, so it means 205,600 numbers, to be in safe side, it should be default size * 6, so lets say 6500

Comment: I set it 10000 and it worked. I really appreciate your help. Many many thanks :) @Sercan

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad that I could help :)